# Is there a verb meaning "to select through sortition"?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

Assuming [*sortition*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sortition) refers to any form of random event used to choose something or someone, and does not refer to the "random" choosing of something/someone by an exterior person (which would somewhat suggest a faint form of volition). At least I think it doesn't?

Thank you !

Comment: Don't you mean "random selection"?

Comment: @HotLicks Could you explain the difference ? Is _random selection_ more general than _sortition_?

Comment: [This crossword solver page](http://www.the-crossword-solver.com/word/select+at+random) gives **draw** as the answer to the clue/definition *select at random*. That seems good enough to me. Or in the unlikely event you can rely on your target audience understanding the noun *sortition*, just apply the standard verbification principle available in English, and use it as a verb.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Any chance you could make that an answer (because dang you answer a lot of questions in comments, this is like the third time I've seen you around unanswered ones)

Comment: @QPaysTaxes: I'd never even heard of the word *sortition* before seeing this question, and I've absolutely no idea why OP says *the "random" choosing of something/someone by an exterior person  suggests **a faint form of volition***. But I do know that used as a verb in this sense, ***to draw*** almost always has a *human* subject. Even though the "computer" that "selects, generates" winning UK premium bond numbers is anthropomorphised by being called "Ernie", I'm not sure many people would talk about *the numbers that Ernie drew last week*. So I dunno how OP feels about that one.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm sorry I've not made that clearer, but by " 'random' choosing of something/someone by an exterior person" I meant something like a person picking up a random person in a list of names, which I believe is somewhat "less random" than a computer selecting a number or someone drawing a numbered ball from a sack. By the way, I had neither heard of _sortition_ before I looked up wikipedia to translate the French expression _tirer au sort_., for which google translate issued _draw lots_, _cast lots_ and _draw lot_ as translations --- which appeared to me as incorrect in the context.

Comment: Much might depend on your exact context. But I would say that if *you* didn't know "sortition" before either, it's probably not a good idea to use it as a verb anyway, since your target audience aren't likely to know it either. Besides which it sounds rather "dated/archaic" to me (OED have no citations later than 1887). Remember the magician's standard *Pick a card*, which invariably implies a *random* choice, even though this isn't usually explicitly stated.

Comment: Your question text reads as *Assuming A and B. At least I think it doesn't?*. Please rephrase to make the question text make sense on it own, independent of the title.

Answer (score 1):

Right. From a definition of [sortition](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sortition?s=t) that I find much easier to understand than your wikipedia link, it means:

> the casting or drawing of lots

The direct verb form of this would be **to draw lots**. A more generic (and more common phrase) in English is **to randomly select**.

---

With regards to your objection to a person picking from a list not being truly random: it isn't. And if it's not actually random, then it's not random selection. I'm afraid there isn't really a simple word/phrase that differentiates between "*random*" and "*I call it random when it's actually pseudo-random, but I believe it's close enough to random to call it random*".